# Is String in Rust basically a vector?

Tags: string, rust

From the [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.8.0/src/libcollections/string.rs#L263-L265):

```
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>, // <- ?
}

impl String {
    // ...
    pub fn new() -> String {
        String { vec: Vec::new() } // <- ?
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question :)

Comment: You can even move out the vector using [`String::into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no. The underlying buffer that `String` uses to save its data is a `Vec`. This makes sense, because often you want similar allocation strategies for both strings and vectors. Doing all the allocation by hand in the `String` impl would be a waste of time and a lot of duplicate code.

Note, however, that the `vec` field is private, so you can't access it directly (using only safe methods). This means that the (safe) `String` interface can enforce valid UTF8 data in the vector.

But yes: `String` is just a UTF8-enforcing wrapper around some kind of buffer.

---

There was a fairly long discussion just prior to the release of Rust 1.0 about whether or not to expose this internal vector via the interface. The result of the discussion was to keep the problematic method [`as_mut_vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.as_mut_vec). This method is of course handy in some cases but makes it impossible to change the implementation of the string later on.

Comment: Should that be `as_mut_vec`?

Comment: @mcarton Absolutely! Thanks, will fix that.